# Wordpress fetch row and display in select options list

Tags: sql, wordpress, while-loop

This is what I´ve got so far:

```
global $wpdb;    
$sql = "SELECT Cause FROM `wp_test` WHERE Accepted = 1 ORDER BY Name";

$res = $wpdb->get_results($sql);


echo "<select name = 'venue'>";
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) != null)
{
    echo "<option value = '{$row[???]}'";
    if ($selected_venue_id == $row[???])
        echo "selected = 'selected'";
    echo ">{$row['???']}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

The code before the while loop works. How do I make the while loop to return my columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you are [`WPDB`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class for your queries the you don't need to use `mysql_*` family functions all work is done by this class,You just have to loop over `$res` it contains the data returned by query

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT Cause FROM `wp_test` WHERE Accepted = 1 ORDER BY Name";
$res = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
if (!empty($res)) {
    echo "<select name = 'venue'>";
    foreach ($res as $key => $val) {
        echo "<option value = '" . $val->Cause . "'";
        if ($selected_venue_id == $val->Cause)
            echo "selected = 'selected'";
        echo ">" . $val->Cause . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew the mysql thingee was wrong but this is exactly what I needed to see. Not a very good coder but I learnt a lot from this. So thanks.